# Import PDF Image From MatPlotLib to ReportLab

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, matplotlib, reportlab, pypdf

I am trying to insert a saved PDF image into a ReportLab flowable.

I have seen several answers to similar questions and many involve using Py2PDF like this:

```
import PyPDF2
import PIL

input1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(path+"image.pdf", "rb"))
page0 = input1.getPage(0)
xObject = page0['/Resources']['/XObject'].getObject()
    for obj in xObject:
        #Do something here
```

The trouble I'm having is with a sample image I've saved from MatPlotLib as a PDF. When I try to access that saved image with the code above, it returns nothing under `page0['/Resources']['/XObject']`.

In fact, here's what I see when I look at page0 and /XObject:

'/XObject': {}

Here's the code I used to generate the PDF:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center',
        color='green', ecolor='black')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')

ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.savefig(path+'image.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a work-around, I'm saving my PNG from MatPlotLib with 1200 DPI. Looks great and almost as good as vector (unless you zoom in very close), but there are downsides, of course (i.e. larger file size).

Comment: matlotlib and pypdf are not related. You cannot expect to pass native objects of either of them an get anything meaningful.